# Short if statement

Tags: php

I have found something weird...,
I have this piece of code at the end of my function:

```
return $class == 3?"red":$class==2?"orange":$class==1?"yellow":"";
```

Now, when `$class == 2` this returns "yellow" and not "orange" like I expected.
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Its the ternory operator in php which is equivallent to if else statement

Comment: Is it a typo, or real code? The missing '$'-sign in front of your last 'class' ?

Comment: Please RTFM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen its a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parentheses as ternary operators are left-associative in PHP. Associativity is how "*operators of the same precedence are grouped in the absence of parentheses*" - from [Operator Associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)

```
$class  == 3?"red":($class ==2?"orange":($class ==1?"yellow":""));
```

Comment: I solved it with an array: $colors = array("","yellow","orange","red"); return $colors[$class];

Comment: I just wanted to know why it wasn't working, not a different approach. You and @Voitcus gave me the correct answers.

Comment: Ah sorry I will edit my answer and remove the suggested alternative approach. The array method you wrote above is a good solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is because it is treated like it was:

```
return (($class == 3?"red":$class==2)?"orange":$class==1)?"yellow":"";
```

So add brackets to force the right use:

```
return $class == 3?"red":($class==2?"orange":($class==1?"yellow":""));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would never code it like that. I believe that when you are coding, you really want to see immediately what a piece of code is doing. This won't do that, this is just giving you headaches ;-)

Maybe change it to something clear:

```
switch($class) {
    case 1:
        return 'yellow';

    case 2:
        return 'orange';

    case 3:
        return 'red';

    default:
        return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use parentheses:

```
$class  = 2;
echo $class == 3?"red":($class==2?"orange":($class==1?"yellow":""));
```

Output : `orange`